# Azure App Service and Office365 SMTP, emails not being delivered but no errors reported

Tags: laravel, azure, smtp, office365

We have a Dockerized, Laravel app hosted on Azure's app service platform which sends emails using our client's Office365 SMTP setup.

During the whole development phase we were hosting on an Azure app service using the default `*****.azurewebsites.net` URL and could send emails all day without issue.

As soon as we moved to an app service with a custom URL, the emails stopped. I'll mention that we're using port 587 with TLS as I understand Azure blocks SMTP on port 25.

So I can't figure out if it's one of these issues:

- Some setting in the app service that I can't find (I feel like I've looked everywhere!)
- I'm seeing hints of the client needing to update DNS records but I can't pin down what might need updating
- Something else entirely

Apologies if this is way too vague but I've hit my limit and need some help.

Comment: I assume it was configured to use port 587 right from the development phase? Are you using an O365 Relay without authentication or a service account? Are there any logs you can get from your O365 portal?

Comment: Yes, we used the same credentials throughout the entire dev phase. The client's set up an email address for this project and it is being authenticated. The client doesn't see anything from their SMTP logs even indicating the emails are arriving there.

Comment: Ok got it, what makes you think DNS records might be an issue? I'm not sure if it would have anything to do with SPF records on the custom domain, usually for SPF misconfiguration, emails would still be received but as spam. In your case the client isn't receiving them at all on Exchange Online. Worth to check if SPF has the outbound IPs configured (check under web app's properties) Is that a newly purchased/configured domain or something that was already in use before / Is the domain used for the email the same as the custom domain?

Comment: Does the web app logs output/errors? If yes can you check logs under log analytics of the web app? Are you able to remove the custom domain and set it back to xxxx.azurewebsites.net to validate it's still working?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. There's nothing appearing in the Laravel logs or in the app service log. I'm even logging the Mail::to response and it's NULL which from what I gather means everything's fine. 

That subdomain is brand new for this application. I was thinking that the DNS would need an SPF TXT record as per the MS docs and another SO question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/set-up-spf-in-office-365-to-help-prevent-spoofing?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Ok what about the sender domain? Is it the same as the custom domain configured? Has that changed too after the custom domain was configured? If you suspect it has to do with the domain/exchange/dns setup try to use your local machine to send an email (use a powershell script or just any application you have that can have an smtp relay configured) while authenticating with the same credentials.

Comment: Emails work on my dev machine and on bone stock Azure app services with the same credentials. It's just something about this one with a custom domain (everything else about the service is the same as the stock ones).